# How to gradually output csv data as file download?

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to output a large amount of data (about 13k rows) in csv format reading it from a database.

Now the problem is that the server loses a lot of time in the fetching/parsing data phase and the browser get stuck until all data is collected and output to browser as file attachment.

Is there a way to force PHP to gradually output data taken from DB to the browser emulating the readfile() function behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: You could use javascript to request a line of data from a php file and then display it. Php cannot do dynamic stuff like that, it only displays stuff all at once really. (if thats what you mean by output, if you mean actually download the file I dont see why you would want to limit the speed on that. Servers like to do stuff fast)

Comment: @lemondrop PHP can output stuff gradually. And OP does not want to limit the speed, he wants to output as soon as possible, without keeping stuff in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unbuffered query.